# Настроить чпу в htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить ЧПУ таким образом, чтобы ссылки типа site/index.php/test?param=0 обрабатывал файл в корне index.php, при этом чтобы в $_GET попадала часть test?param=0. Пробую вот такой вариант

```
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1
```

Но в $_GET попадает только часть после / и до ?, то есть ['q'] => ['test']. Мне нужно получить в $_GET

['q'] => ['test'], ['param']=> [0]

Comment: `[QSA]` добавьте

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```